# What is the default capacity of Text Area in HTML?

Tags: html, textarea

I am using a Text Area in my project. Having rows="20", height say "10px" and width is also "10px".

How many number of characters can we save in the specified textArea?

Comment: You'll know if you try to do it.

Comment: Many thanks Tushar, i will know it after trying. But it is saving every time i increase the characters. I just want to confirm if there is any default capacity (in case we haven't specified any MAX length )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textarea does not have a hard limit for as far as I know.

So unless you set a limit on the textarea or have a limit in the language you process the data with then textarea input lenght is limited, Otherwise you can just continue adding data untill your browser crashes :p.

I tested 100K characters and it still posted and saved to database using `PHP`, I don't know if other languages have a standard limit.

`rows="20"` Does not limit maximum amount of characters allowed. It only limits the amount of rows allowed in the field.